# ethers gasLimit gasPrice

Tags: javascript, uniswap, ethers.js, bsc

I am a noob.. I am trying to set `gasPrice` and `gasLimit` since I am getting a gas estimation error.

I just don't understand where/how to insert it into the transaction.  This is on the BSC network.

Error message:

```
ERROR:
reason: 'cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit',
    code: 'UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT',
    error: Error: gas required exceeds allowance (3807079) or always failing transaction
```

```
  const tx = await router.swapExactTokensForTokens(
    amountIn,
    amountOutMin,
    [tokenIn, tokenOut],
    addresses.recipient,
    Date.now() + 1000 * 60 * 3 //3 minutes
  );
  const receipt = await tx.wait(); 
  console.log('Transaction receipt');
  console.log(receipt);
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Let's break this into two parts, with the caveat that you should look at the second before doing anything about the first.

### Setting the `gasLimit` and `gasPrice` in Ethers

[Here](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/contract/contract/#Contract--write)'s the relevant part in the docs, but let's explain it. Whenever you make a transaction through Ethers, you can set `overrides` in an object after your arguments. In this case, this is your original contract call:

```js
const tx = await router.swapExactTokensForTokens(
    amountIn,
    amountOutMin,
    [tokenIn, tokenOut],
    addresses.recipient,
    Date.now() + 1000 * 60 * 3 //3 minutes
  );
```

So if you wanted to set a `gasPrice` of 100 and a `gasLimit` of 9M, you'd put:

```js
const tx = await router.swapExactTokensForTokens(
    amountIn,
    amountOutMin,
    [tokenIn, tokenOut],
    addresses.recipient,
    Date.now() + 1000 * 60 * 3, //3 minutes
    {
        gasPrice: 100,
        gasLimit: 9000000
    }
  );
```

and that's it!

**Note:** there is no reason to set a high `gasPrice` in this case. The problem here is that there either isn't enough gas or an internal error, not that you aren't paying enough for gas. In general, though only in general, low gas prices won't make your transactions fail, just make them take a long time to get mined. `gasLimit` is what regulates *how much* gas you can spend, so increasing it can theoretically help (though probably not in this case, see below).

### Digging into the error

But before you run off to set a high `gasLimit`, let's look at that error:

```
ERROR:
reason: 'cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit',
    code: 'UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT',
    error: Error: gas required exceeds allowance (3807079) or always failing transaction
```

the error lists two possible causes:

1. the gas limit is too low (`gas required exceeds allowance`)
2. there is an error (`always failing transaction`)

You get how to fix the first, but how do you know if it's the first or the second? There is a hint here - the estimator tells you what it set the `gasLimit` at: 3807079. Taking a quick look at [GasNow](https://gasnow.org) it looks like Uniswap v2 (which is the basis for the code for the exchange on BSC that you're using) is ~34.5K gas. This is a hint that something else is wrong.

It's worth spelling this out because the state of accurate error messages is not so developed currently, so you can run into errors like this a lot, and it's good to know how to look at them and get clues.

So the gas hints at another error. Looking at the code you supplied, and comparing it to code in the Uniswap docs (I used a snippet on [this](https://uniswap.org/docs/v2/javascript-SDK/trading/) page for reference), it looks like there's one big difference between their code and yours in the `deadline` parameter.
Your code:

```js
Date.now() + 1000 * 60 * 3, //3 minutes
```

Theirs:

```
Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 60 * 20 // 20 minutes from the current Unix time
```

The big difference is that they're using `Math.floor()` to ensure they don't have any decimals. You are most likely putting a float as the `deadline` arg, and there is a good chance that it's causing things to fail. (They also divide by 1000 as opposed to adding it, which means that your amount isn't 3 minutes like you thought - `Date.now` returns the time in milliseconds ([Source](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_now.asp).) Try wrapping that line in `Math.floor` (and dividing by 1000 instead adding).

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to help me out.. this was huge. I have added  Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 60 * 3, // 20 minutes from the current Unix time
    {
        gasPrice: 5,
        gasLimit: 210000
    }                                                                                                                                                                                now just getting an error code: -32000,
  response: '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":5,"error":{"code":-32000,"message":"transaction underpriced"}}\n',
  transaction: {

Comment: Did you know how to solve the problem with transction underpriced?